# PostGIS - st_intersects using polygons that cross antimeridan/equator

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, geography, intersect

New to using PostGIS and have two situations that I'm working with.

In the one case, I have a polygon that crossed the antemeridian and was detecting whether a two separate points located within that polygon one on the west and one on the east side of the antimeridian intersects with the polygon (data types used are geometries). I found I had to use the `st_shift_longitude` on the geometries passed to the `st_intersects` function.

The other situation is a polygon crossing the equator with points above and below the equator within the polygon. `st_intersects` doesn't detect both points intersect the polygon. Do the latitudes need to be shifted in this case? I didn't see a shift latitude function available.

I'm using the following points and polygon at the equator:
st_point(170.0,45.0)
st_point(170.0,-45.0)
and the polygon 'POLYGON((165 40,175 40,175 -50,165 -50,165 40))'

I'd expect that the st_intersect function return true for both points, however, it's only returning true for st_point(170.0,-45.0)

Comment: Can you add the points and the polygons?

Comment: FYI, "anti" = opposite versus "ante" = before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum latitude of your polygon is 40. The latitude of your missing point is 45. I think you just have a typo in your test.